# How to parse a few lines in array text file in fortran

Tags: parsing, fortran

I'm new to Fortran, and I want to parse a few lines to an array from 
a big text file like below. After I read the complete file, I separated the
file into a few parts. And I want to parse specific lines into , `L(i)`, 
and write a few columns from lines. I tried to write a small part
of the program. I read all lines from the text file, but I don't know how 
can I parse specific `Line(i)`.

text file:

...
...

```
     a          b         c          d
  1.2564E+2 0.2564E+2 1.25047E+2 3.2564E+1
  1.2564E+2 0.2564E+2 1.25047E+2 3.2564E+1
  1.2564E+2 0.2564E+2 1.25047E+2 3.2564E+1
  1.2564E+2 0.2564E+2 1.25047E+2 3.2564E+1
```

.....
.....

```
  character*256 Line(155)
  integer ierr, n, i, s
  real:: a, b, c, d

  open(10,file='b.txt', status='old')
  do i=1,155
    read(10,'(a)',iostat=ierr) Line(i)
    if (ierr /= 0) exit
    end do
  close(10)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may read from a character variable using `read`:

```
do i = 1, 155
   read(line(i), *) a, b, c, d
   print*,'a =',a
   print*,'b =',b
   print*,'c =',c
   print*,'d =',d
enddo
```

If you are not planning to use `Line` for anything else, you could have done that in the first place, reading `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` directly from your file.

Comment: Thanks your comment, I can read all line similar you wrote. But I need parse few specifiv Line(i). There are variables in each line. For example, I want to parse Line(60) like a,b,c,d, and only write b,d values.

Comment: I don't quite understand - you can put an if construct in the loop which only processes values when you want it.

Comment: that's ok. I have 155 lines (whole lines), and I describe Line(i)'s array, and then read all lines. And then, firstly I write i=1,15 whole lines into other file. Right now, I want to formatted write just a few variable into whole lines i=16-20. For formatted writing, I should parse Line(16,17,18,19,20) and then write variables like c,d. I dont know how can I do parsing progress. Thanks your helps.